# Loading CPU in Linux for performance testing

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

I need a exe which I can run in my Linux machine which can load the CPU to a mentioned percentage. For Example if I run the exe with 50 as command line argument then my CPU should be loaded for 50 percentage. Please provide your suggestions/solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Short version: A process that only takes 50% CPU is impossible (see below for an alternative solution).

Long version:
All the instructions a process wants to do are done as quickly as possible. The only way a process would stop running is when:

- The process exceeded it's allocated time slice
- Another process gets a higher priority with a preemptive scheduling algorithm, thus bouncing the original process off the CPU. (this also happens with interrupts)
- The process becomes blocked (mostly caused by waiting for I/O)

The CPU percentage you see in `top` or Windows Task Manager is an average on how busy the CPU was over the last x time. However, a CPU always runs full speed, so 50% usage over 1 second means for 500ms it was running code and for 500ms it was sleeping.

---

Solution

There is a tool called `cpulimit` on Linux. You can use it like so:

```
cpulimit -p 1313 -l 30
```

This will limit PID 1313 to maximum 30% CPU usage. According to the [website](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/), it works like this:

> The work of cpulimit is done all in userspace, so it doesn't interfere
>   with the Linux scheduler. Basically, the target process, which you can
>   specify by pid, name, or command line, is continuosly paused and
>   resumed by sending it SIGSTOP and SIGCONT signals. Signals are sent by
>   cpulimit in appropriate moments, based on the limit specified by user
>   and the process statistics read from /proc.